# Why does YoutubeDL extract only the first index of a playlist?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm doing a project that's related to playlists and I made a class which inherits from YoutubeDL.

```
class Playlist(youtube_dl.YoutubeDL):
    info = {}

    """
    Base class for any playlist. Inherits from youtube_dl.YoutubeDL and overrides some methods to make sure that the
    link is an actual playlist and implements some cool stuff to make playlist loading easier.
    :var info: the stored information from the extract_info() method
    :type info: dict
    """

    def extract_info(self, url, download=False, ie_key=None, extra_info=None, process=True, force_generic_extractor=False):
        """
        Loads the playlist info and make sures the link is a playlist

        :param url: the link with the info to be loaded
        :param download: will it download?
        :param ie_key: see youtube_dl's doc
        :param extra_info: see youtube_dl's doc
        :param process: see youtube_dl's doc
        :param force_generic_extractor: see youtube_dl's doc
        :return: extract_info(...)["entries"] = self.info
        :rtype: list
        """
        info = super(Playlist, self).extract_info(url, download, ie_key, extra_info, process, force_generic_extractor)


        if "_type" not in info:
            raise BaseException("\"_type\" not in \"info\"!\n" + info.__str__())
        if info["_type"] != "playlist":
            raise NotPlaylistError("The url %s does not appear to be a playlist" % url)

        self.info = info["entries"]

        return self.info

    def download(self, url_list=list()):
        """
        The inherited download method - now can be used without parameters. If no url_list specified, uses self.info
        :param url_list: the url list to be downloaded
        :return: nothing
        :rtype: None
        """

        super(Playlist, self).download(url_list if url_list else self.info)
```

So I've simply added a playlist with `Playlist().extract_info(my_url)`. But it raised a `KeyError` which was caused by a `"_type"` key. Thus I played with the code a bit and I found out the code was downloading only the first index of the entire playlist (the actual code posted here is already handling that by raising a `BaseError`). Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you post the [**complete**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code you used to *play with the code a bit*? As of writing, youtube-dl has 893 extractors, many of which can return playlists, so the behavior may vary a lot. Does the problem persist if you remove the custom `download` method?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should probably review [the specification of the info](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py#L74) you're looking at. For instance, a missing `_type` is equivalent to the _type `'video'`. Thus, a proper check for info to be a playlist is simply

```
if info.get('_type', 'video') != 'playlist': ..
```

Your program will also break or do random stuff when someone calls `download` without arguments. `YoutubeDL.download` expects a list of URLs for its first parameter (named `url_list`).

If `extract_info` has not been called before, `YoutubeDL.download({})` will be called. This works currently, but `{}` is no list, and thus conceptually the wrong format. But luckily, this will just do nothing.

However, if `extract_info` has been called before, and you have advised youtube-dl to **not** extract detailed information (for example you activated the `listformats` option to your instance of YoutubeDL), then `self.info` will be a list of infos, not a list of URLs.

If `extract_info` has been called before with default options, youtube-dl will **recursively** call extract_info on every element of the playlist. On each invocation, you overwrite `self.info` with the entries (luckily, as far as I understand, the playlist will win out, but that's incredible brittle code). However, [as documented](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/37768f92422c2cf61a961dbaf54d61dabd364506/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py#L266), each item will be a dictionary, not a URL. Likely, you've picked up one of the intermediately set values.

Subclassing may be needlessly complicated as well, especially for a Python beginner. It is likely [easier and more flexible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Finally, beware that at its current description, you may be victim of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Fundamentally, youtube-dl handles a playlist of one item and a single video very similarly, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to distinguish the two.

Comment: The answer is too long and - sorry, but - I don't get what I did wrong.

Comment: I agree with lucas. I don't see your point. You just reviewed the code, but didn't answer the main issue.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not putting in a video - I'm putting in a playlist. By default, I know YoutubeDL extracts all the playlist's info. But this is not happening in this case. I don't think this would be an instance of the XY problem. If it is, please be more clear. :)

Comment: @LucasHenrique If so, can you amend your question to [a **complete** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I feel that all I can do is point out the shortcomings of your implementation, and present a theory to your answer. How exactly did you *find out that the code was only downloading the first index*? Also, please do include your ultimate goal; why, for instance, do you abhor single videos?

Comment: I'm making a playlist-only script. `Playlist` is a base class for `FilteredPlaylist`, `LocalPlaylist` and a lot of different implementations. My implementation used a `LocalPlaylist` (that inherits from `FilteredPlaylist` - that inherits from `Playlist` again) and failed. So I tested it with `Playlist().extract_info(playlist_page_url)` (as pointed out in the question) and it failed **the same way**. So the problem is more elementar. The code in the question has to have some error...

Comment: *Why* are you making a playlist-only script? But more importantly, can you post a very short **complete** example? That is required, because among others, depending on what value `playlist_page_url` has, one of hundreds of different extractors is used.